# Deleting documents from Cosmos Db collection during incremental load using Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from Azure SQL to Azure Cosmos Db Collection (Mongo API). I am using upsert to insert/update the documents on Cosmos Db. However, if any data from source is deleted, how do I delete that document from Cosmos Db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware,it is impossible to deleting documents from Cosmos Db collection during incremental load.

Because,incremental load is comparing `LastModifytime`.If you delete rows in azure sql,them  don't exist in source and copy data only supports `insert` and `update`.

If you want to synchronized your data,please delete them in cosmos db manually.
You can run the delete sql in cosmos db or add a column `DeleteStatus`.When you want to delete data,update `DeleteStatus` and `LastModifytime`then incremental load.Finally,run the sql both in cosmos db and azure sql:

`delete from xxxx where DeleteStatus = 1`

Hope these can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was also looking if we could recreate the collection before data load using ADF. But that would warrant a full load every time :(